# Probability of uniform distribution $P(Y > 12)$ , $Y = 3X^2$ and $X\sim U(-3, 4)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

**My Problem**

> Let X be a uniformally distributed random variable such that X ∈ U(-3, 4).
> Let Y = 3X<sup>2</sup>
> What is P(Y > 12)

**Solution**
P(Y > 12) = 0.43

**My attempt of solving the problem**
X ∈ U(-3, 4)
P(Y > 12) = P(3X<sup>2</sup> > 12) = P(X<sup>2</sup> > 4) = P(X > 2)
If we try to calculate P(X > 2) in wolfram alpha we get ([see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=uniform%20distribution%20min%20%3D%20-3%20max%20%3D%204%20P%28X%20%3E%202%29))
0.28574

**My Question**
I am clearly not getting the correct answer.
What am I doing wrong?
I am very thankful for any help and/or guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that there are two square roots for any positive real number—one positive and one negative.
$$\mathsf P(X^2>4)=\mathsf P((-2>X)\cup (X>2))$$

Comment: thanks, I know get the correct solution https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=uniform+distribution+min+%3D+-3+max+%3D+4+P%28X+%3C+-2%29+%2B+P%28X+%3E+2%29